# Redirect to jsp page from another jsp page through servlet when button is clicked?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Login.jsp from where I want to redirect to another jsp page when button is clicked but it is getting only in servlet page and not redirecting from there to another jsp page i.e. CustomerLogin.jsp

```
    <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/UserController" name="login" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action">
<table align="center">
    <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="user"> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login"> </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

servlet coding

```
    String requestSource=request.getParameter("source");

    if(requestSource.equalsIgnoreCase("home")){
        System.out.println(requestSource);
        response.sendRedirect("jsp/Login.jsp");
    }
    else if(requestSource.equalsIgnoreCase("CustomerLogin")){
        System.out.println(requestSource);
        response.sendRedirect("jsp/CustomerPage.jsp");
    }
```

Comment: And where exactly is this "source" parameter coming from?

Comment: "source" parameter i am using with servlet to redirect my pages in controller according to different values of source of different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a parameter called `source` in your `<form>`. You may add this parameter as a hidden:

```html
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/UserController" name="login" method="post">
    <!-- current content... -->
    <input type="hidden" name="source "value="customerLogin" />
</form>
```

Then your `requestSource` variable will be filled with this parameter.

Still, note that this isn't a good approach and you should not rely on hidden fields to support navigation. Define the navigation through specific data for the user like role (obtained in the process of user authentication) or another.